# Full Calendar if start is same with end dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have full calendar and when getting the data for event I get error in this line

```
end: event.end.format() || event.start.format(),
```

saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

According to [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fullcalendar/issues/1014)

a work around is

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end || start;
}
```

but it didnt work for me

What is the best way to handle end date in full calendar

```js
eventData = {
  id: id,
  sysid: sysid,
  title: title,
  start: event.start.format(),
  end: event.end.format() || event.start.format(),
  description: description,
  otherinformation: otherinformation,
  page: page,
  action: action

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is it checks for *truthy* ofthe formatted value, it doesn't evaluate whether `event.end` is *truthy*. So when `event.end` evaluated to `falsey` the error is thrown.

You should check for `event.end` to be *truthy*, thus use

```
end: (event.end || event.start).format()
```

Or, As suggest by API Docs

```
var start = event.start;
var end = event.end || start;

eventData = {
  end: end.format(),
};
```